# Dynamic UITextView query iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have put questions in table list. When I check each tableRow the question should added to UITextView dynamically in next line. Once the whole TextView get filled then we can save this textView page with questions on it. Is this possible?

Right now I have taken 6 different Textview for each question which get converted in to PDF page.

Thanks in advance for your code/suggestion:)

Answer (score 7):

For creating the pdf document use the following code

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  PDFProject
//


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

#define kBorderInset            20.0
#define kBorderWidth            1.0
#define kMarginInset            10.0

//Line drawing
#define kLineWidth              1.0

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
  CGSize pageSize;
}
- (IBAction)generatePdfButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath;
- (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNum;
- (void) drawBorder;
- (void) drawText;
- (void) drawHeader;
- (void) drawImage;
@end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) drawBorder
{
CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor brownColor];

CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(kBorderInset, kBorderInset, pageSize.width-kBorderInset*2, pageSize.height-kBorderInset*2);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, borderColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kBorderWidth);
CGContextStrokeRect(currentContext, rectFrame);


}

- (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
NSString* pageNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d", pageNumber];
UIFont* theFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

CGSize pageNumberStringSize = [pageNumberString sizeWithFont:theFont
                                           constrainedToSize:pageSize
                                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect stringRenderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset,
                                        pageSize.height - 40.0,
                                        pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset,
                                        pageNumberStringSize.height);

[pageNumberString drawInRect:stringRenderingRect withFont:theFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];


}

- (void) drawHeader
{
CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0);

NSString *textToDraw = @"Pdf Demo - iOSLearner.com";

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];

CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

[textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];


}

- (void) drawText
{
CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

NSString *textToDraw = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.";

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset)
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

[textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect
              withFont:font
         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
             alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];



}

- (void) drawLine
{
CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kLineWidth);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(kMarginInset + kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(pageSize.width - 2*kMarginInset -2*kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);

CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

CGContextClosePath(currentContext);
CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathFillStroke);


}

- (void) drawImage
{
UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"];
[demoImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - demoImage.size.width/2)/2, 350, demoImage.size.width/2, demoImage.size.height/2)];


}

- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

NSInteger currentPage = 0;
BOOL done = NO;
do
{
    //Start a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    //Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
    currentPage++;
    [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

    //Draw a border for each page.
    [self drawBorder];

    //Draw text fo our header.
    [self drawHeader];

    //Draw a line below the header.
    [self drawLine];

    //Draw some text for the page.
    [self drawText];

    //Draw an image
    [self drawImage];
    done = YES;

    }
while (!done);

// Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();




}

 #pragma mark - View lifecycle


 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {



[super viewDidUnload];
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}



 - (IBAction)generatePdfButtonPressed:(id)sender
 {
pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

[self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
}


@end
```

Comment: Sorry. I am done with PDF generation. I just would like to know dynamically adding question text on to TextView after every row selection.